# DotNetOpenAuth with Google Provider fails works on localhost but fails on test server - return_to realm issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth

I am using DotNetOpenAuth to perform my website authentication using Google accounts with ASP.NET MVC 4.  I am able to run Google authentication without any problems on my localhost, but when deploying to test I get the following error.

```
 DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException: return_to '...//myserver/myapp' not under realm '...//myserver/myapp/'.
```

Notice that the only difference in the return_to realm parameters is the trailing slash "/".  If I enter .../myserver/myapp/ (including the trailing slash) in the browser's address bar the site then works.

How do I get my application to accept both trailing and missing slashes when entered in the browsers address bar?

Below is my code:

```
IAuthenticationRequest request = openId.CreateRequest(Identifier.Parse(WellKnownProviders.Google));

FetchRequest fr = new FetchRequest();
fr.Attributes.AddRequired(WellKnownAttributes.Contact.Email);
request.AddExtension(fr);

request.AddExtension(new ClaimsRequest
    {
    Email = DemandLevel.Require,
    });

return request.RedirectingResponse.AsActionResult();
```

Thanks in advance for any help!